# phpMyAdmin - Syntax Error when importing excel sheets

Tags: syntax, phpmyadmin

When trying to import a zip file containing excel spreadsheets relating to my created databases I get the following error message:

````
5 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 358)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "AcID" at position 0)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Title" at position 5)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "CaID" at position 11)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "BuID" at position 16)
SQL query: Copy

AcID,Title,CaID,BuID,Status,Started,Ended,Internal 1,New Programme Promotion,1,1,On Going,2021-02-01',NULL,1 2,Coding Competition,2,2,Finished,2019-01-01',2019-01-30',1 3,Drone Design Workshop,1,3,Finished,2018-11-14',2018-12-14',1 4,Welcome Party,3,4,Planning,2023-01-18',2023-01-30',1 5,Summer Undergraduate BBQ,1,5,Finished,2016-06-07',2016-06-08',1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AcID,Title,CaID,BuID,Status,Started,Ended,Internal
1,New Programme Promotion...' at line 1```



Any Ideas?
````

Comment: Column names with spaces in them need to be surrounded by backticks. Did you try checking the documentation for your MySQL version, which is readily available with a simple Google search? The first line of the errors list tells you that as well, with `Ending Quote` followed by a backtick.

Comment: @KenWhite The MySQL documentation is not likely to have information on doing an Excel import through phpMyAdmin, though.

Comment: How big is your zip file, and how big are the original Excel files? Please try uncompressing them locally and importing the .xls directly rather than uploading the .zip file; it could be that phpMyAdmin is encountering a timeout or memory limit uncompressing the files. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using and how were the Excel files generated?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch: The MySQL documentation has information about the proper way to do a SELECT and the need to escape table and column names that contain spaces, which is the issue here.